# Jackson HttpMessageNotReadableException : Already had POJO for id

Tags: jackson, bidirectional

I dont understand what is wrong in birectional relationship deserializing :

Serialized Registration is :

```
{
uuid: "d3372f25-ac70-4735-b756-7894977142b2",
    payment: [{
        "uuid":"15363b3f-7057-4658-3f63-3f3f695d7019",
        "type":0,
        "amount":10
        "registration":"d3372f25-ac70-4735-b756-7894977142b2"
   },
   {
        "uuid":"ee9fb135-2b21-48f4-a1ee-2f71f09f44ab",
        "type":0,
        "amount":5
        "registration":"d3372f25-ac70-4735-b756-7894977142b2"
   }] 
}
```

Java is :

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "uuid", scope = Registration.class)
public class Registration implements Serializable {}

@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "uuid", scope = Payment.class)
public class Payment implements Serializable {}
```

> Could not read document: Already had POJO for id (java.util.UUID) [[ObjectId: key=d3372f25-ac70-4735-b756-7894977142b2, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration]] (through reference chain: com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration["payment"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.mezoo.tdc.model.Payment["registration"]->com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration["uuid"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for id (java.util.UUID) [[ObjectId: key=d3372f25-ac70-4735-b756-7894977142b2, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration]] (through reference chain: com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration["payment"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.mezoo.tdc.model.Payment["registration"]->com.mezoo.tdc.model.Registration["uuid"])"

Somebody can explain to me why deserializing doesnt works please ?

Comment: care to elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have edited my post